# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I got a problem with my android application. I want to connect the android application to a webservice that runs on jboss 7.1. When I create an asynchronous task to run a method on my webservicde, I get the following errors in logcat:

```
06-15 15:45:21.731: E/Trace(1958): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at   de.wifhm.se1.android.banking.OnlineBankingSystemStub.login(OnlineBankingSystemStub.java:52)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at de.wifhm.se1.android.LoginActivity$LoginLogoutTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:118)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at de.wifhm.se1.android.LoginActivity$LoginLogoutTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     ... 3 more
```

The android manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.wifhm.se1.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:name=".OnlineBankingApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TransactionsActivity" android:label="@string/labelTransactions"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".PrefsActivity" android:label="@string/labelPrefs"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my doInBackground method:

class LoginLogoutTask extends AsyncTask {

```
/**
 * Diese Methode wird in einem nebenlÃ¤ufigen Thread ausgefÃ¼hrt (asynchron). Darum dÃ¼rfen hier
 * keine View-Elemente zugegriffen werden!
 */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    StringBuffer output = null;
    if (LoginActivity.this.obsApp.getAngemeldeterKunde() == null) {         
        /* Login durchfuehren */
        String username = LoginActivity.this.prefs.getString("username", "");
        String password = LoginActivity.this.prefs.getString("password", "");
        Kunde angemeldeterKunde = LoginActivity.this.obsApp.getObsStub().login(username, password);
        LoginActivity.this.obsApp.setAngemeldeterKunde(angemeldeterKunde);

        //Ergebnisausgabe:
        output = new StringBuffer("Sie sind eingeloggt als " + angemeldeterKunde.getUserName() + ".\n\nIhre Konten:\n");

        Set<Konto> konten = LoginActivity.this.obsApp.getObsStub().getEigeneKonten();
        for (Konto konto : konten){
            output.append("- Konto " + konto.getKontoNr() + "\n");
            output.append("---Kontostand aktuell: " + LoginActivity.this.obsApp.getObsStub().getKontostand(konto.getKontoNr()) + "EUR\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        /* Logout durchfuehren */
        LoginActivity.this.obsApp.getObsStub().logout();
        LoginActivity.this.obsApp.setAngemeldeterKunde(null);
        output = new StringBuffer("Bitte erneut einloggen.");
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Read carefully the line 52 of `OnlineBankingSystemStub.java` and check what is null.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace points to your code failing on a call to `login` inside your `doInBackground` method.  This is shown by the following lines from your stack trace:

```
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at   de.wifhm.se1.android.banking.OnlineBankingSystemStub.login(OnlineBankingSystemStub.java:52)
06-15 15:45:45.531: E/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at de.wifhm.se1.android.LoginActivity$LoginLogoutTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:118)
```

With that in mind, your code makes one call to `login` and the result is `NullPointerException`:

```
    String username = LoginActivity.this.prefs.getString("username", "");
    String password = LoginActivity.this.prefs.getString("password", "");
    Kunde angemeldeterKunde = LoginActivity.this.obsApp.getObsStub().login(username, password);
```

Most likely you have a problem in your code where either `username` or `password` is being set to null. Possibly both.

You will need to investigate the rest of your code to determine why one or both of these missing from `prefs`.

Comment: Log.d(TAG, response.toString()); The SOAP response is null. Maybe the connection to my webservice doesnt run? How can i test it?

Comment: So you've found some new information about where this occurred?... You can edit that into your question.  That's the etiquette here.  The thought that anyone can be allowed to write "online Banking" code when they don't know simple debugging skills is really very worrying.  I presume you're using eclipse.  I suggest you learn how to use breakpoints and step through your code line by line.  You can add a break point on the line that should set the variable that's ending up null.

Answer (score -1):

Andy is busy at the moment. Here is the prefs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference android:key="username" 
        android:summary="@string/summaryUsername" 
        android:title="@string/titleUsername"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="password" 
        android:summary="@string/summaryPassword" 
        android:title="@string/titlePassword" 
        android:password="true"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and the strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="myTitle">Willkommen zum OnlineBanking</string>
    <string name="app_name">OnlineBankingApp</string>
    <string name="titleUsername">Benutzername</string>
    <string name="summaryUsername">Joe</string>
    <string name="titlePassword">Kennwort</string>
    <string name="summaryPassword">Joe1</string>
    <string name="labelPrefs">Einstellungen</string>
    <string name="labelTransactions">Transaktionen</string>
    <string name="bnLogin">Login</string>
    <string name="bnLogout">Logout</string>    
    <string name="bnTransactions">Transaktionen</string>    
    <string name="msgLoginFehlt">Bitte loggen Sie sich ein.</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: If he's busy we'll wait until he read the line 52 of `OnlineBankingSystemStub.java` and check what is null.

Comment: Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

The SOAP response is null. Maybe the connection to my webservice doesnt run? How can i test it?